# Print all the numbers! (At least, as many as possible.)

Tags: code-challenge, string, number, answer-chaining

Your task is to print a number. Simple, right? It is simple, but not as simple as this. The first answer is to print the number 1, the second answer is to print the number 2, etc.

### Rules

1. The first answer must print 1, and the `n`th answer must print `n`.
2. The first answer may be of any length.
3. Whitespace, comments, etc. are permitted.
4. The next answer's submission's length must within 1 unit of the previous answer's length. That is, if a submissions length is `L`, the next submission must be of length `L + 1` or `L - 1`. The length is measured in characters, not bytes.
5. No language may be used more than once.
6. No person may answer earlier than eight hours after their most recent answer.
7. No person may answer twice in a row.
8. You may not use a REPL environment.

To win, you must have the most valid answers to this question. You may use a language updated after/ made later than this challenge so long as the language was not intended to answer this challenge.

### Answer template

All answers must conform to this template.

```
# Answer N, Lang name, M characters

    program

 optional description
```

### Leader board

A leader board will be maintained here in this section. (If anyone wants to create a leader board counting the number of submissions a person has, I will give them a 50 rep bounty on any answer to this question.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad, as, quote: "_There are either too many possible answers..._"

Comment: @CoolestVeto How?

Comment: How can you win?   This can go on forever.  The winner just changes constantly?

Comment: @RikerW I guess that it's a question of who can find the most languages to answer in. However, another plausible criterion is the person with the most answers after <x amount of time> without any new answers.

Comment: The idea is good, but it needs something to make it harder after each answer. This would have benefited from some time in the sandbox.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 I think that is a good idea.

Comment: This is far too broad in my opinion. You can basically fill your code with no-ops until the desired number of bytes is reached.

Answer (score 4):

## Answer 8, [Carrot](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/), 3 bytes

```
8^
```

Note the trailing space.

Answer (score 3):

## Answer 2, GolfScript, 1 character

```
2
```

Pushes the number 2 to the stack.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer 4, CJam, 3 characters

```
2))
```

Pushes 2 and increments twice.

Other solutions:

```
C4/
D5%
T3+
```

Answer (score 3):

## Answer 5, dc, 2 characters

```
5p
```

Pushes `5` and `p`rints it.

Answer (score 3):

## Answer 6, pl, 3 characters

```
6⌂⌂
```

The last two characters are no-ops.

Answer (score 3):

## Answer 7, Befunge, 4 characters

```
43+.
```

Add 4 to the stack, then 3, add the top 2 stack values, then print the top value as an int.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer 10, PowerShell, 3 chars

```
+10
```

Even when not golfing we need to golf. :) Frustratingly, though, here the `+` is superfluous, but we can't go down to 2 chars since the Fission answer was 4.

Comment: [Related](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PNK5t.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

### Answer 12, [MSM](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MSM), 3 characters

```
.21
```

`.` concatenates the two rightmost elements `2` and `1` to `12`. MSM stops when there's only one element left.

Answer (score 3):

## Answer 14, [Pylons](https://github.com/morganthrapp/Pylons-lang), 3 characters.

```
B4+
```

Pushes 10 and 4 to the stack and then adds them.

[Try it online](http://pylons.tryitonline.net/#code=QjQr&input=)

Answer (score 3):

## Answer 13, TI-BASIC, 2 characters

```
13
```

Pretty much.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer 15, 05AB1E, 4 characters

```
4o<?
```

[Try it here.](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=NG88Pw&input=)

Basically, it does 2^4 - 1.

Comment: I based my answer on valid answers, ignoring the PHP one.

Comment: Your language caught my attention on another challenge, so I tried it :D Thanks for creating it @AandN !

Comment: Haha, no problem :). It's always nice to see someone else use 05AB1E too :).

Comment: Note: This language is pronounced Osable, not Usable or Osabie.

Comment: ...It didn't even occur to me it was a word. Welp

Answer (score 2):

## Answer 1, Retina, 0 characters

The empty program outputs the number of matches on the input. Since the empty program matches the input once, 1 is outputted.. [Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net)

Comment: that was fast. that reminds me i need to include an answer template

Answer (score 2):

## Answer 3, Vitsy, 2 bytes

```
3N
```

Pushes three, outputs three.

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=M04&input=)

For lols, verbose mode:

```
push 3;
output top as number;
```

Comment: Damnit, was going to post a Vitsy answer. >.<

Comment: @RikerW Vitsy'd.

Answer (score 2):

## Answer 9, [Fission](https://github.com/C0deH4cker/Fission), 4 characters

```
R'9O
```

Creates an atom moving right
Sets its mass to character value of 9
Outputs the ascii character of the mass and destroys the atom

[Try it online](http://fission.tryitonline.net/#code=Uic5Tw&input=)

Answer (score 2):

### Answer 11, Pyth, 2 characters

```
11
```

Yawn...

Answer (score 2):

## Answer 16, [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki), 3 characters

```
⁴OO
```

The two `O`'s was just to fill the remaining 2 characters. [Test here.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oG0T08&input=&args=)

Comment: You should've waited till there's a shorter answer in the chain ;)